# Having trouble setting background of an event with its ID | WxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I believe I've done something similar in wxPython where I've changed an event by grabbing the Id or object and setting the object's background from there. In WxWidgets I seem to be having trouble though, I keep on getting errors like  `operator -> or ->* applied to "int" instead of to a pointer type`. I'd like to be able to get the event's parent's Id/object and the event's Id/object in order to change their background/properties. I also had no luck in finding anything that mentioned an event's parent in the documentation.

I've tried different using different methods like `GetEventObject()` and `GetEventUserData()` and making the EventId a pointer. I'm new to C++ so pointers are still new to me so I didn't expect anything to work. Any help is much appreciated.

Code:

```
void MyFrame::OnMenuTxtBtnLeftClick(wxMouseEvent& event) {
    int EventId = event.GetId();
    EventId->SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(217, 217, 217, 19));
```

Comment: `EventId` is an `int` and thus the operator `->` cannot be used with it.

Comment: @AnoopRana What do I do to make it so I can use ->?

Comment: You can just use `SetBackgroundColour` directly without any `->`. Like `SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(217, 217, 217, 19));` or `this->SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(217, 217, 217, 19));`

Comment: What is the type of the object whose background colour you want to set. I mean what is the name of the class like `myPanel`, `myButton` etc?

Comment: @AnoopRana its a panel, Basically, I want it so that when the panel or text in the middle of it is clicked the panel's background is set to grey. So I can't set it using this since that would set it for the whole frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is that `EventId` is an `int` and thus the operator `->` cannot be used with it.

You can try out the following that uses `GetEventOjbect`:

```
wxObject *obj = event.GetEventObject();
((myPanel *) obj)->SetBackgroundColour(wxColour(217, 217, 217, 19)); 
//^^^^^^^----------------------------->use your own type here
```

Comment: I think this should work its not giving me any errors but it may take a while for me to verify I'm trying to sort out how to put the function in the event table :(

Comment: @Pal Ok, when you verify this just leave a message here so that i can know the status.

Comment: ok the background turned grey but the previous background is still on top of it, when I move the panel outside the window and move it back in again, that's when it completely turns grey, do you know any quick fixes for this?

Comment: alright well thanks for this fix, wouldn't have figured it out otherwise I don't think

Comment: for reference, I fixed the background issue by excluding the function from the event table

Comment: @Pal Good to hear that.